# How can i toggle state in an Object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to toggle `inernalstatus` based on `externalValues`. If `valueOne` is true, then `statusOne` is true. If `valueTwo`is true, then `statusTwo` is true and `statusOne`is false.

```
const externalValues = {
 valueOne: false,
 valueTwo: false
}

const [internalStatus, setInternalStatus] = useState({
 statusOne: false,
 statusTwo: false
  })

// what i have tried so far
useEffect(() => {
 setInternalStatus(prevValue => {
  for (const key in externalValues) {
   internalStatus[key] = !externalValues[key]
  }
 })}, [])
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-bash-mgrt4z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Do not mutate state in React.

Comment: How do the values for ```externalValues``` changes? And passing the externalValues in dependency array might help

Comment: I am assuming he maybe storing the data in external file or keeping some predefined information.  @SatyamSaurabh

Comment: If for a given number `key`, `internalStatus[key] === !externalStatus[key]`, then you should derive `internalStatus` from `externalStatus` directly without using `useState`.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const externalValues = {
    valueOne: false,
    valueTwo: true
  };

  const [internalStatus, setInternalStatus] = useState({
    statusOne: false,
    statusTwo: false
  });

  useEffect(() => {

    const clonedInternalStatus = {...internalStatus}
    const externalValuesKeys = Object.keys(externalValues)
    const internalStatusKeys = Object.keys(internalStatus)
    for(let i = 0; i < externalValuesKeys.length; i++){
      clonedInternalStatus[internalStatusKeys[i]] = externalValues[externalValuesKeys[i]]
    }
    setInternalStatus(clonedInternalStatus)

  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {internalStatus["statusOne"] + " " + internalStatus["statusTwo"]}    
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-haslett-px1ktx?file=/src/App.js